# $stockItem->getIsInStock() stopped working after update to 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, upgrade, stock, cataloginventory

example code:

```
$stockItem = $product->getStockItem();
$stockItem->getIsInStock()
```

The product is one item of a collection.
Before the update I could Request the isInStock status in this way.
After the Update this always returns `Null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The StockItem is not automatically loaded from Database anymore.
You need to add the associated Data to your collection, which is also a bit more efficient then to load the data for every product separately.

You can do this via:

```
Mage::getModel('catalogInventory/stock')->addItemsToProducts($productCollection);
```

or the more efficient way, if you only want to filter them:

```
Mage::getModel('catalogInventory/stock')->addInStockFilterToCollection($products);
```